How to set up a firewall for a wireguard vpn
I am trying to make a VPN server using PiVPN on a Debian 12 Virtual machine. I am able to connect to the VPN but I am not able to connect to the internet.
PiVPN doesn't natively support nftables but it should be able to use it if I set it up myself. If I'm wrong please let me know.
I have used this script for nftables to configure it but not directly edited the config file. I've left the virtual machine running while testing and verifying that the rulesets have been applied. The value of the lan variable is not my real lan ip address, 10.0.0.0 is a placeholder. Is there anything wrong with my script? Most importantly does the rule in the postrouting chain work like I think it should.

flush ruleset

define lan = 10.0.0.0-10.0.0.190

table inet filter { 

    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0;
        iifname lo accept;
        jump baseRules;
        tcp dport ssh ip sdarr $lan accept;
        policy drop;
    }

    chain baseRules { 
        ct state { established,related} accept;
        ct state invalid drop;
        ip6 nexthdr icmpv6 icmpv6 type echo-request limit rate 2/second accept;
        ip protocol icmp icmp type echo-request limit rate 2/second accept;
    }

    chain forward { 
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy accept;
    }

    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
    }

    chain postrouting { 
        type nat hook postrouting priority 0; 
        oifname ens0 masquerade;
        policy accept;
    }

}


"Is there anything wrong with my script?" is a very broad question, especially when you haven't indicated whether or not it works when you use it. Do these rules result in the behavior you want?
